# Sort field separator problem in external awk call if its semicolon

Tags: sorting, awk

I have one csv semicolon separated and I want to sort some field without the header keeping the header untouched.
If I use colon as field separator don`t have problem to do, but don´t know to do this with semicolon as field separator.

file temp2:

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
3,1,2,3,1
2,3,1,2,3

>cat temp2 | awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -t, -k2"}'
```

result ok sorting field 2:

```
a,b,c,d,e
3,1,2,3,1
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,1,2,3
```

Next try, do the same but the semicolon field separator:

file temp1

```
a;b;c;d;e
1;2;3;4;5
3;1;2;3;1
2;3;1;2;3


 >cat temp1 | awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -t=";" -k2"}'
```

result the file its untouched:

```
a;b;c;d;e
1;2;3;4;5
2;3;1;2;3
3;1;2;3;1
```

The result expected:

```
a;b;c;d;e
3;1;2;3;1
1;2;3;4;5
2;3;1;2;3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need awk for this:

```
$ head -n 1 file; tail -n +2 file | sort -t';' -k2
a;b;c;d;e
3;1;2;3;1
1;2;3;4;5
2;3;1;2;3
```

Having said that, this inside your awk command:

```
"sort -t=";" -k2"
```

means this:

```
("sort -t=") ; (" -k2")
```

i.e. your nested double quotes are actually terminating the string that you want to use for sorting inside the command. There's also an error where you're using `-t=";"` instead of `-t";"` so let's assume that's fixed. Now:

You would use this instead:

```
"sort -t\";\" -k2"
```

or even better wrt shell quoting rules:

```
"sort -t\047;\047 -k2"
```

wrt your comment below about it not working in awk, look:

```
$ awk 'NR==1; NR>1{print | "sort -t\047;\047 -k2"}' file
a;b;c;d;e
3;1;2;3;1
1;2;3;4;5
2;3;1;2;3
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, this work but want to do the same on awk,calling sort.

Comment: @User1234141414 I don't know what that means. Everything after that first script IS how to call sort within awk as you're trying do do, I'm just fixing your syntax. I updated my answer to show it working in awk.

Comment: This work fine in the shell but if I want to do this sorting for data that comes from other pipe (or awk result) in a script, the new pipe in the awk sentence make some problem, anyone there can aproach to the solution to this? (awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file ` ' for reading (No such file or directory)
)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question you asked (how to make sort in awk work with ; like it does with ,). Ask a new question if you have one.

Comment: You are right Ed, I will try by other ways And if I cannot get work I will make a new ask, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Had maked a new try and it´s solved there for a cmd call of awk need to close the statement or "open file" even if there hasnt the "file", this is for the limit in pipe, so, awk its very powerfull but need to be handle with care, never before I had to open other command in awk, but I dont´t know very well how to handle sort of array´s in awk, maybe go to try to learn how to do it with arrays with this example.